# Cannot acess image in React native project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, visual-studio, image

I am trying to import and use an image but no matter what path i try it won't recognize the images.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pq2zE.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4TBr.png)

I even right clicked and did copy path and copy relative path. I tried change where in the directory it was in.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add code as text, not as images. Take a look at [ask] when you can. Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

there is an extension on vscode to check if the import of the image is correct, if it's the preview of the image will show like this:

[image]

This is the extension, make sure that your image is showing like the mine
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try import image source is to obtain image source url.

```
import tigerImage from '../../assets/images/tiger.jpeg';
```

and pass this tigerImage as src value

```
<Image source={picImage} />
```